# Dereference variables at class initialization

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my code for initializing the class dictionary:

```
class Directory:
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.__dict__.update(kwds)
obj = Directory(name=dict())
```

In the above case, the key is `name`, and can be accessed using: 
`obj.__dict__.['name']` or `obj.name`

Q1.How can I initialize the class dictionary with key value being a variable's value?

The code should look like something:

```
name = 'bin'
obj = Directory(name=dict()) #here I want the variable `name` to be replaced by its value i.e. `bin`
```

Q2.Are there other optimal ways of implementing the class? (may be `__slots__`)

Thanks!

Comment: This will no doubt require some `eval` dark magic if you leave things as is. Consider using `setattr()` instead.

Comment: Thanks Rafe. It serves the purpose. If I omit the usage of class, and merely do `obj = dict()` will it be a good practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Am I right in thinking that you want to be able to call the constructor with keyword arguments, but use the value of the variable as the argument name, rather than the variable name itself?

It can't be done with that precise syntax, but here are a couple of other syntaxes you could use:

```
name = 'bin'
obj = Directory(**{name: dict()})
```

If you're happy with that syntax, you can just use it without having to change the class (it will just work).

Another syntax, if you only want to set a single value:

```
name = 'bin'
obj = Directory(name, dict())
```

If you're happy with that syntax, you can support it by rewriting the class like this:

```
class Directory:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.__dict__[name] = value
```

For Q2, `__slots__` isn't what you're looking for. It lets you specify "all members of this class have the same fields" (thus avoiding the need to have a dictionary). You have a prime example of where you *can't* use `__slots__` because all instances of your class may have different members.